# write a shell script to find a binomial coefficient c(n,k)

Tags: shell

```
fact()
{
    echo $1
    i=1
    f=1
    while [ $i -le $1 ]
    do
        f=`expr $f \* $i`
        i=`expr $i + 1`
    done
    echo $f
    return $f
}
echo enter value of n
read n
echo enter value of k
read k
fact $n
r1=$?
echo $r1
r2=`expr $n - $k`
fact $r2
r3=$?
echo $r3
fact $k
r4=$?
echo $r4
r5=`expr $r3 \* $r4`
echo $r5
result=`expr $ / $r5`
echo $result
```

I can not understand why first factorial is not returned correctly in-spite of the fact that it is calculated correctly. 
Suppose if i am entering n as 7 and k as 3, factorial of 7 is calculated as 5040 but 176 is returned.
[this is the output screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QgYZ.png)

Comment: Please tell us the exact input you give, and the exact output you get, as well as the expected output. Do it by editing your question.

Comment: done...thank for the quick reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks like a Bash script. The [Bash manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html) says:

> **return** [n]
>
> Causes a  function  to  stop  executing  and  return  the  value specified  by *n* to  its  caller. If *n* is omitted, the return status is that of the last  command  executed  in  the  function body.  If **return** is executed by a trap handler, the last command used to determine the status is the last command executed before the  trap  handler. If return is executed during a DEBUG trap, the last command used  to  determine  the  status  is  the  last command  executed by the trap handler before **return** was invoked. If **return** is used outside a function, but during execution of  a script by  the **.** (**source**) command, it causes the shell to stop executing that script and return either *n* or the exit status  of the  last  command executed within the script as the exit status of the script.
>
> If *n* is supplied, the return value is its least significant 8 bits. The return status is non-zero if return is supplied a non-numeric argument, or is used outside  a  function and  not  during  execution  of  a  script  by **.** or **source**.  Any command associated with  the RETURN trap is  executed  before execution resumes after the function or script.

Note that **return** is intended to be used for the purpose of setting an exit status; as a consequence, the value is limited to 0 to 255.

Normally, shell functions return results by **echo**ing them. For example:

```
factorial() {
  [[ "$1" -lt 2 ]] && echo 1 && return
  echo $(( $1 * $( factorial $(($1 - 1)) ) ))
}

$ echo $(factorial 7)
5040
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fact()  
{  
    i=1  
    f=1  
    while [ $i -le $1 ]  
    do  
        f=`expr $f \* $i`  
        i=`expr $i + 1`  
    done  
    echo $f  
}  
echo enter value of n  
read n  
echo enter value of k  
read k  
r1=$(fact $n)  
r2=`expr $n - $k`  
r3=$(fact $r2)  
r4=$(fact $k)  
r5=$(echo "scale=2; $r3*$r4 " | bc)   
result=$(echo "scale=2; $r1/$r5 " | bc)  
echo $result  
this is the final code i came up with.... all thanks to you @alexp
```